# How to keep Vuetify form open after submitting, if server responds with an error

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify form (contained in a v-dialog), which when submitted posts data to a server. All working if the server accepts the data, but if the server returns an error the form closes and the user has to start from scratch with filling in all the fields. How can the the form be left open until a correct response is received from the server?

```js
async function submit() {
  const {valid} = await signupForm.value?.validate()
  if (valid) {
    const username = userName.value;
    const pass = password1.value;
    const email = eMail.value;

    creds.value = { name: username, pw: pass, email: email, code: 0 };
    
    myFetch(apiMethods.signup,creds.value)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response != null) {
          Alert('Registration',response,'','info','OK');
          signupDialog.value = false;
          emit('doneSignUp');
          }
          else {
            signupDialog.value = true;
          }
      })
  }
}

function cancel() {
    signupDialog.value = false;
    emit('doneSignUp');
}
```

```html
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="signupDialog" activator="parent" >
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title class="headline black" primary-title>
      Sign Up to RideHub
    </v-card-title>
    <v-card-text class="pa-5">
      <v-form @submit.prevent ref="signupForm">
        <v-text-field v-model="userName"  :rules="nameRules"  label="User name"></v-text-field>
        <v-text-field v-model="eMail"     :rules="emailRules" label="Email"></v-text-field>
        <v-text-field v-model="password1" :append-inner-icon="showPass ? mdiEye : mdiEyeOff"
          @click:append-inner="showPass = !showPass"   :type="showPass ? 'text' : 'password'" 
          :rules="pwRules"  label="Password">
        </v-text-field>
        <v-text-field v-model="password2" :append-inner-icon="showPass ? mdiEye : mdiEyeOff"
          @click:append-inner="() => (showPass = !showPass)" :type="showPass ? 'text' : 'password'"
          :rules="pwConfirmRules" label="Confirm password">
        </v-text-field>
        <v-btn color="blue" type="submit"  @click="submit()" block class="mt-2">     Submit      </v-btn>
        <v-btn color="blue" variant="outlined" @click="cancel()" block class="mt-2">   Cancel    </v-btn>
      </v-form>
    </v-card-text>

  </v-card>
</v-dialog>
</template>
```

Comment: You should use some form or error signal in the response from the server. For example, the server can respond with this JSON for success `{"success": true}` and with another JSON for failure `{"error": "Invalid username"}` By checking the response, your code can determine whether to close the dialog or not.

Comment: Already doing this; `myFetch` displays the error from the server and then returns `null`, so the code goes to the line `signupDialog.value = true`

Comment: Your dialog must be closing a different way.  You should show all code relevant to your dialog, especially any code related to opening/closing.  VDialog has some ways of closing itself, so there may be some important props you need to add or remove.

Comment: @yoduh ok, I have added the full template. Dialog visibilty is controlled by `signupDialog' and all uses of this are shown in the code .

Comment: Your server should return the error as a HTTP status code above 399, e.g. 400. If you want to get the error as HTTP status code 200 - then according to your code, the error must be represented as `NULL` in the response from the server.